# How can I individualize the order of rows in heatmap.2 (gplots)?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, heatmap

I am interested in visualizing the distribution of my outcome variable using `heatmap.2`, as provided in the `gplots` package.

This is what my *dataset* looks like:

```
> head(data.w)
year Armenia Azerbaijan Bulgaria Croatia Cyprus Czech Republic Estonia Georgia 
1998       0          0     1.14       0   1.21           1.32    1.43       0    
1999       0          0     1.32       0   1.44           1.50    1.68       0  
2000       0          0     1.32       0   1.63           1.59    1.75       0  
2001       0.75       0     1.46       0   1.85           1.93    1.81       0  
2002       0.82       0     1.74       0   2.04           2.00    2.00       0.34  
2003       0.87       0     1.85       0   2.22           2.22    2.19       0.42
```

To draw the **heatmap**, I use the following *code*:

```
library(gplots) 
library(grDevices)

min(data.w[,2:9]) 
max(data.w[,2:9]) 
data.wx <-as.matrix(data.w)

pdf("heatmap.pdf", width=10,height=5)
heatmap.2(as.matrix(t(data.w[,2:9])), trace="none", 
          Rowv=NULL, Colv=NULL, dendrogram="none",
          labCol=data.w$year,labRow=data.w$cname,
          lhei=c(0.1,1), lwid=c(0.1,1), margins=c(5,10),
          colsep=1:16, rowsep=1:9, sepcolor="white",
          col=gray.colors(8, start=1, end=0) ) 
dev.off()
```

Overall, I am rather happy with what the plot looks like:

[image]

Yet, the countries displayed actually belong to **two different groups**, with Armenia, Azerbaijan, and Georgia belonging to the group "neighbourhood" and the remaining countries being members of the group "enlargement".

In short, *I would like to split the heatmap by group membership.* Within each group, countries should not be listed alphabetically or according to values but I would need to individualize the order according to some specific criteria.

Importantly, I do not want to

- draw two separate plots as this would change the distribution of
  colours;
- group the row variable by using `RowSideColors` as
  additional argument, as for instance suggested [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/heatmaps_in_r.html) in order to
  categorize the input variables.

Rather, the final heatmap should be organized as follows:
[image]

*What would I need to add to the plot in order to get such heatmap.2 in which the order of rows is individualized?
Please note that extra space between the rows separating the groups is not needed.*

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sebastian Raschka [http://sebastianraschka.com] was so kind and helped me out with a solution to my problem that I am happy to share.

If you want to avoid that the rows (here: names of countries) are alphabetically ordered, you should write a function that orders the countries in the DataFrame as desired. For the sake of simplicity and to stick with the example, you can also quickly do it manually with such a small number of countries:

```
data.w <- data.w[c("Cyprus","Czech Republic","Estonia","Bulgaria","Croatia","Armenia","Azerbaijan","Georgia")]
```

We then overwrite the heatmap.2 function `reorderfun` with a placeholder function, which, however, won't "do" anything so that we keep the order of the DataFrame.

Overall, this is what the code should look like in order to produce a heat map as shown above (2nd image).

```
heatmap.2(as.matrix(t(data.w)), trace="none",
          Rowv=NULL, Colv=NULL, dendrogram="none",
          reorderfun=function(d,w) { d },
          labCol=data.w$year,labRow=data.w$cname,
          lhei=c(0.1,3), lwid=c(0.1,3), margins=c(5,8),
          colsep=1:16, rowsep=1:22, sepcolor="white",
          col=gray.colors(8, start=1, end=0)
          )
```

Thanks a lot Sebastian!

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal, in the above case I think you can do it by removing the `Rowv=NULL,` but keeping the `Colv=NULL, dendrogram="none",` which will order the rows but suppress the dendrogram from being plotted.

With just the data in the head I got this [heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWXVl.png) 
with this code:

```
data.w = t(matrix(c(1998,       0,          0,     1.14,       0,   1.21,           1.32,    1.43,       0,    1999,       0,          0,     1.32,       0,   1.44,           1.50,    1.68,       0,  2000,       0,          0,     1.32,       0,   1.63,           1.59,    1.75,       0,  2001,       0,          0,     1.46,       0,   1.85,           1.93,    1.81,       0,  2002,       0,          0,     1.74,       0,   2.04,           2.00,    2.00,       0, 2003,       0,          0,     1.85,       0,   2.22,           2.22,    2.19,       0),9,6))
colnames(data.w) = c("year", "Armenia", "Azerbaijan", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Estonia", "Georgia")
group = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)
library(gplots) 

heatmap.2(as.matrix(t(data.w[,2:9])), trace="none", 
      # Rowv=NULL, Colv=NULL, 
      dendrogram="none",
      # reorderfun = group,
      labCol=data.w[,1],#labRow=data.w$cname,
      lhei=c(0.1,1), lwid=c(0.1,1), margins=c(5,10),
      colsep=1:16, rowsep=1:9, sepcolor="white",
      col=gray.colors(8, start=1, end=0) )
```

When you add in the rest of the years, Croatia will separate from the other three.

Otherwise it should be possible to do it with the `reorderfun` option but I don't know how it works.

Comment: Thanks Vincent! Yes, indeed, for the given example it might be enough to set Rowv to TRUE. Yet, the actual dataset includes many more countries with different values. so that this solution does not yield the intended effect. I was hoping for a more general solution that would also be applicable to different data -- I have edited my question accordingly.